# Trigger selection of a TableViewRow from ViewModel

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I have a UITableView (with a corresponding TableViewSource) added to a MvxViewController. This ViewController has a ViewModel. Is it possible to select a table row (visually) via data binding by just changing a property in my viewmodel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code for anything you've tried yet but I recently had a similar problem.  I solved it by sending a Message from my viewmodel and listening for it on the view.

The code in my view looks like this when I need to select the row.

```
var path = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(MainViewModel.Inspections.IndexOf.(MainViewModel.SelectedInspection), 0);         
MainTableView.SelectRow(path, true, UITableViewScrollPosition.None);
```